# Loader dissapears but image not rendered entirely

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling, dom-events

I have quite a few static photos on my page.  My goal is to show a loader while the page and the image loads.  The problem is after my loader disappears, the image is not fully rendered yet.

How can I make the loader disappear after the images fully rendered?

Here is my current attempt from a different source.

Javascript:

```
(function(){

  function id(v){return document.getElementById(v); }

   function loadbar() {
var ovrl = id("overlay"),
    prog = id("progress"),
    stat = id("progstat"),
    img = document.images,
    c = 0;
    tot = img.length;

function imgLoaded(){
  c += 1;
  var perc = ((100/tot*c) << 0) +"%";
  prog.style.width = perc;
  stat.innerHTML = "Loading "+ perc;
  if(c===tot) return doneLoading();
}
function doneLoading(){
  ovrl.style.opacity = 0;
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    ovrl.style.display = "none";
  }, 1200);
}
for(var i=0; i<tot; i++) {
  var tImg     = new Image();
  tImg.onload  = imgLoaded;
  tImg.onerror = imgLoaded;
  tImg.src     = img[i].src;
}    


}document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadbar, false);}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the image in the body

```
...
function doneLoading(){
  ovrl.style.opacity = 0;
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    ovrl.style.display = "none";
  }, 1200);
  //you should put
  document.body.appendChild(this);
}
...
```